# Intersection of Topologies, I would like to know if the proof is well.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let {$\tau_i:i\in I$} be any collection of topologies on set $X$.Then the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i$ is also a topology on $X$.

**Proof:** 
since it is a family $\left \{ \tau_i \right \}_{i\in I}$ of topologies, it has to $X,\emptyset \in \left \{ \tau_i \right \}_{i\in I}$. 
 Hence for all $i\in I$, it has that $X,\emptyset \in \tau_i$, hence $X,\emptyset\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i$.

Now, let $\left\{U_j \right \}_{j \in J} \subset \bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i $, hence $\forall_{i\in I}, \left\{U_j \right\}_{j\in J}\in \tau_i$, as $\tau_i$ is a topology $\forall_{i\in I}$, it has that $\bigcap_{j\in J}U _j\in \tau_i, \forall_j\in J$, hence $\bigcap_{j\in J}U _j\in \bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i, \forall i$.

Let  $\left\{U_j \right \}_{j\in J} \in \bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i$, hence:

$\forall_{i\in I}, \left\{U_j \right \}_{j\in J} \in \tau_i$, since $\tau_i$ is a topology then, $\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\tau_i$.

Hence $\left \{ \tau_i \right \}_{i\in I}\subset Top(X)$.

Comment: Nitpick: $X$ and $\varnothing$ are not elements of $\{\tau_i\}_{i\in I}$. They are elements of **each** $\tau_i$ (saying they are elements of $\{\tau_i\}_{i\in I}$ is saying that $X$ is equal to some $\tau_j$ and $\varnothing$ is equal to some $\tau_k$). Similary, you don’t want to say that the *family* $\{U_j\}_{j\in J}$ is an element of the intersection, you want to say that the family is such that *each* $U_j$ is an element of the intersection. Etc. The ideas are all fine, but what you are writing is not *quite* right with respect to what is an element of what.

Comment: Note that you need to check only finite intersections, not general intersections. A topology $\tau_i$ might not be closed under infinite intersections.

Comment: The idea behind the proof seems correct to me. You should note that $J$ in the second part, is a *finite* set. Also, to have the same clarity as in the intersection part, you should add an intermediate step that $\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j\in\tau_i$ for all $i\in I$. Also, some of your notation is off, for example $\{U_j\}_{j\in J}$ is not an element of $\tau_i$, but a subset thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, but you should be more precise.

(1) You should not write $\left\{U_j \right \}_{j \in J} \in \bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i$, but $\left\{U_j \right \}_{j \in J} \subset \bigcap_{i\in I}\tau _i$.

(2) When you consider intersections, you should mention that $J$ is finite.